# How do i plot small, close values so that the difference is more visible?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So i want to plot a small and close values to see the difference between them. I'm using matplotlib.pyplot.plot
but the y limits are too big compare to my data which is:

```
2.663689859547342e-08
7.999154916053879e-09
7.99915525716199e-09
7.999155333718048e-09
```

code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,12))
plt.grid()
plt.yscale('log')
plt.scatter([1,2,3,4],norm_vector)
```

[image]

Can i scale the y limits so that my values difference is more visible?

Comment: Yes with [matplotlib.pyplot.ylim](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html#matplotlib-pyplot-ylim)

Answer (score 1):

#### You can get or set the y limits of your y axis -

```py
bottom, top = ylim()  # return the current ylim

ylim((bottom, top))   # set the ylim to bottom, top

ylim(bottom, top)     # set the ylim to bottom, top
```

#### or you could just specify the bottom or up -

```py
ylim(top=3)  # adjust the top leaving bottom unchanged

ylim(bottom=1)  # adjust the bottom leaving top unchanged
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I just used plt.plot to produce scatter and y limits changed.

```
plt.plot([1,2,3,4],norm_vector,'bo')
```